# Excluding UTM Parameters from a specific domain in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am looking to strip UTM parameters in Analytics for a specific domain. We used to work with this company as an affiliate, so their sales get pulled into the "Affiliates" default channel grouping. After terminating the relationship they have not pulled their links down or removed the UTM, so the sales they drive still get lumped into "Affiliates" default channel grouping and skews my data.

I want this traffic to come through as referral, after Analytics strips the UTM parameters ONLY for this domain. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yu have to create a function to strip UTP and send the url stripped as custom value of page parameter.

Function like this:

```
function stripUTM(url) {
  var s = url.replace(/utm_[a-z]+=(.*?)(&|$)/g, '');
  return h;
}

var theUrl = 'http://example.com/?utm_campaign=test&utm_medium=test&utm_source=test&z=last&m=middle&a=first&t=upper-middle';

console.log(stripUTM(theUrl));
```